# MimeMessage.getContent - Unknown encoding: 8bitPrecedence

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

When I get emails from POP3, comes the following error

```
Fatal exception java.io.IOException: Unknown encoding: 8bitPrecedence
at javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream(MimePartDataSource.java:109)
at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:107)
at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:790)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:537)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1419)
```

Source code

```
Session session = property.getSession();
HashMap<String, String> isNotified = Util.getIsNotified(connection, userId);
store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect();
inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
int count       = inbox.getMessageCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Message message     = inbox.getMessage(i);
    Object content = message.getContent();
}
```

Other messages received without any error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the message is corrupted.  There should be a newline between "8bit" and "Precedence".  You can set the System property "mail.mime.ignoreunknownencoding" to "true" if you just want to ignore these errors.